# How to Build a maven project using script file?

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, maven-3

I have created a maven project in STS.I completed the development and testing code for my project.If now I want to run or build this project, then I have to do the following

```
      Right click on the project-->Run as-->Run on Server   (or)
      Right click on the project-->Run as-->Maven Build
```

If I want to run the test code then

```
      Right click on the class file-->Run as-->Run JUnit
```

But I want to create a text file I mean script file to run all these commands when I run this script file from the cmd prompt. I have found out on a web site that I should create a PowerShell file, So I don't cognize how to compose a script file like this, is there any example file for it ?

Please, anybody can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `mvn clean install` on your project root folder (i.e. where your `pom.xml` file is) in cmd prompt. This command will trigger your project default build lifecycle covering a number of build phases including:

- validate
- compile
- test
- package
- integration-test
- integration
- verify
- install

During these build phases, Maven will validate and compile your project, run tests (if any) against your codes, package the resultant binaries into say, a JAR file, run integration tests (if any) against your JAR, verify it, and then install the verified package to your local `.m2` repository.

If you really want a script, then just add `mvn clean install` to your batch file.

Comment: Suppose if I want to run the project, then what is the command to run the project with tomcat server